# Add Data and header to a new Dataframe and fill file name into a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe in the following format:

```
         fdate          flag     counter      values
0        2008-08-18     0        0            1119881.78
1        2008-08-18     0        1            1922320.74
2        2008-08-18     0        2            3559026.11
3        2008-08-18     0        3            3510447.61
4        2008-08-18     0        4            4873269.42
5        2008-08-18     0        5            5098557.55
6        2008-08-18     0        6            4610888.45
...
800      2008-08-18     0      999           -2177130.73
```

I would like to extend it with empty column headers as defined below. Somehow I receive double columns for `fdate flag counter values`. How can I remove these double columns? Using the following removes all columnes which i added `df.T.drop_duplicates().T`.

How can I add any number e.g. 20 into the column `Group1` for the whole column.

The code looks like the following:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:/File_Workers1_Office_01M.txt',sep=',')

df.columns = ['fdate', 'flag', 'counter', 'values']

print(df)

df_new = df.reindex(columns=[*df.columns.tolist(), 'mem1', 'mem2',  'name_file', 'Group1', 'meth', 'fdate', 'counter', 'values', 'timevalue', 'flag', 'config', 'country', 'value_date'], fill_value=0)

print(df_new)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a new column, for example `Group1`, as a column with all rows having the value `20`, you can do so with a simple assignment:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'fdate': ['2008-08-18','2008-08-18','2008-08-18','2008-08-18'],
                'flag': [0, 0, 0, 0],
                'counter': [0, 1, 2, 3],
                'values': [103, 1422, 12312, 112]})

df['Group1'] = 20
```

Yields:

```
        fdate  flag  counter  values  Group1
0  2008-08-18     0        0     103      20
1  2008-08-18     0        1    1422      20
2  2008-08-18     0        2   12312      20
3  2008-08-18     0        3     112      20
```

You can do the same for adding an empty column, however I'm not entirely sure the purpose of assigning an empty column:

```
import numpy as np

df['Empty'] = np.nan
```

Yields:

```
        fdate  flag  counter  values  Group1  Empty
0  2008-08-18     0        0     103      20    NaN
1  2008-08-18     0        1    1422      20    NaN
2  2008-08-18     0        2   12312      20    NaN
3  2008-08-18     0        3     112      20    NaN
```

Comment: Thanks that was what I was looking for